# Stripe API endpoints parameter missing when testing payments

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, insomnia

I am trying to implement stripe payment in node js without using third-party libraries or npm. So, to start I want to test the requests with insomnia.

Looking at the stripe docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card), I get a success object if I paste the same command in the console.

Now moving to insomnia, I have the following in the request headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer my_api_key
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Then the following object in the body:

```
{
    "card[exp_month]":7,
  "card[exp_year]":2022,
  "card[cvc]":314
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
    "message": "You must supply either a card, customer, PII data, bank account, or account legal entity to create a token. If you're making this request with a library, be sure to pass all of the required parameters for creating a token. If you're making this request manually, be sure your POST parameters begin with the token type. For example, a PII token would require `pii[personal_id_number]`, while an account token would require a parameter beginning with `account[legal_entity]`. See the API reference for more information: https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

1 - Which endpoint, headers, and body content do I use to create a token?
2 - How do I make an actual payment.

Note: I got my test_api_key from the stripe dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to consider here:

1. It's ultimately up to you, but I strongly recommend using the [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) library instead of rolling your own. The library is basically a wrapper for the underlying HTTP requests with some useful features like automatic retries, idempotency keys and robust error handling. You could roll your own, but you'd be reinventing the wheel and would be opening yourself up to all sorts of unhandled edge cases and increasing problems as your integration gets more complex.
2. It looks like you're trying to send raw card details to Stripe. This is strongly discouraged as it would put you in the harshest bracket of [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance). This includes sending Stripe a 40+ page document every year detailing how you implemented security and proving that you adhere to PCI compliance security standards.
3. You're attempting to use the Tokens API, which is deprecated for the use of cards. Instead you should be using the [PaymentMethods API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning) for your new integration.

If you know what you are doing and you still want to go down this path, the problem is that you aren't providing a card number in your request. Alongside expiry date and CVC, the card number is [required](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=php#create_card_token-card-number).